# Iterating and modifying java queue at the same time

Tags: java, iterator, queue

I have a list and a pointer to an element of the list. From time to time I need to:

- append a value at the end of the queue
- remove a value from the head of the queue
- make the pointer advance to the next value in the list

That is:

- from WRITE point of view it's a queue.
- from READ point of view it's a list.

If I use a normal Iterator I get ConcurrentModificationException when modifying the queue; if I use a ListIterator I can only remove/add value at the iterator position.

Is there any standard data structure I can use to achieve this?

Comment: are you writing and reading concurrently from different threads?

Comment: Can you share your current implementation code?

Comment: @assylias I'm on single thread

Comment: See `java.util.LIstIterator`, and the various methods that return one.

Comment: @Jack Then it should be solvable. Can you share an example of code that throws the exception?

Comment: @assylias I really think there is no need to share a code. Instantiate a LinkedList, create it's Iterator. Add a value into the list, and call next to iterator - ConcurrentModificationException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`. It allows **modifying and iterating at the same time** because it includes the necessary mechanisms for synchronization.

The followin snippet shows a working example where there are 3 Threads accessing the same queue without a problem:
1. Iterating and outputting elements
2. Adding new elements once in a while
3. Removing outputted elements once in a while

```
package test;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class QueueListTest
{
    // private static final Queue<Integer> numbers = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final Queue<Integer> numbers = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

        final AtomicInteger insert = new AtomicInteger(0);
        final AtomicInteger output = new AtomicInteger();

        for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        {
            numbers.add(insert.getAndIncrement());
        }

        // print 1 number every 100ms
        Thread t1 = new Thread() {
            public void run()
            {
                Iterator<Integer> iter = numbers.iterator();
                while(iter.hasNext())
                {

                        int first = numbers.peek();
                        int size = numbers.size();
                        int last = first + size - 1;
                        int current = iter.next();

                        System.out.println("list from " + first + " to " + last + " @ " + current);
                        output.set(current);

                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        // add 5 number every 500ms
        Thread t2 = new Thread() {
            public void run()
            {
                while(true)
                {
                    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                    {
                        numbers.add(insert.getAndIncrement());
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        // remove all printed numbers every 1000ms
        Thread t3 = new Thread() {
            public void run()
            {
                while(true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                        int current = output.intValue();

                        while(numbers.peek() < current)
                            numbers.poll();
                }
            }
        };

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();

        try
        {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
            t3.join();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Because the queue is "linked" it should handle **iterating, adding and removing in constant time** and hence be the most efficient implementation you could use.

Comment: Yes, this is probably the structure that best fits my needs. At the same time, given the constraint of being a single-thread, I think that it could have existed a structure without the synchronization overhead, and thus more efficient. What a pity

Comment: To bo honest, you probably want a `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` instead (since you'll be inserting both at the start and at the end). I'm just wondering about the performance overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. The problem is, there's no structure that does what you want in an efficient manner.

- You could use `ArrayList`, iterate over indices and keep an updated current index after inserting at the start (increment by 1), but inserting at the start will not be efficient
- You can't use `LinkedList` because it does not expose the current `Node`

Your best bet would probably be `CursorableLinkedList` from Apache Commons Collections (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/list/CursorableLinkedList.html)

Comment: Of course you can expose a current `Node` when using `LinkedList` by using an `Iterator`. The only problem is concurrency. Therefore you can use a synchronized instance (=> see solution above https://stackoverflow.com/a/50062786/4090157)

Comment: What a pity there is no such a structure. It could be easy to implement (and useful at the same time) under the constraint of having a single thread accessing it. Thanks for the link, I'll give a look

Answer (score 0):

Create a copy of your list before iterating over the items.

Or do you have any other constraints?

Comment: List can be big; i'm looking for an efficient solution. Also, it would be probably more efficient to restart the iterator from head than copy the list